# How do I find the codec I just installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, codec, camstudio

So I just downloaded CamStudio Lossless Codec 1.5 and ran the setup (http://free-codecs.com/camstudio_lossless_codec_download.htm).  I did not see any hints during the setup process as to where exactly it was going to put the codec when it installed. I know it installed because CamStudio found it just fine.  How does CamStudio know where to look for it? Where can I find it myself?

Comment: Maybe you could use [WhatChanged](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php) and install the codec again. It will show you what files and registry keys are modified during the install process. Show us the result, I'd like to know this too.

Answer (score 2):

Open the start menu an search for "MSINFO32," click the icon in the search results to open the System Information window.

In the navigation pane on the left, go to Components -> Multimedia -> Audio/Video Codecs. The pane on the right will show you which codecs are installed on your computer along with their size, location, manufacturer, creation date, and version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how it matters where the codec got installed or how the program is able to locate its own codec, unless you're having problems with it.

That said, search your system for **camcodec.dll**. Since I don't see any 64-bit version available, the file will most probably have landed up in `Windows\SysWoW64`.

Additionally, the codec installer would have registered the codec and so it should show up in one or more of the following registry locations:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\drivers.desc
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the DLL's location, download and run [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It is essentially a more feature-rich version of Task Manager.

Whilst running CamStudio open up Process Explorer. In Process Explorer, click Find -> Find Handle or DLL -> type in the name of your DLL. If you don't know the exact name of the DLL you could make a reasonable guess that it'd be called something close to codec.dll or even camcodec.dll as mentioned above. You should then see the DLL and its file location.

Answer (score 0):

To find the codec DLLs (usually ending in `.ax`) without manual registry hassle, install Mark Russinovich's `Autoruns` tool, which is available standalone or as part of the *SysInternals Suite*. It has a tab that lists all the codecs:

[image: Autoruns, Codec Tab]